# Mean value theorem for integration question

Tags: integration

I have a question below. I would say $3$ with the formula for mean value theorem for integration but I don't see $3$ in the answers. What am I doing wrong?
The function $f(x)=x^2$ assumes the value of its integral average over the interval $[0,3]$.

a) at point $x_0=\sqrt 3 $

b) at point $x_0=\sqrt{5}/2 $

c) at point $x_0=\sqrt{3}/3 $

d) at point $x_0=3/2  $

e) never on the given interval

> [image]

Comment: can you show your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$\int x^3dx$=$\frac{1}{3}x^3$+C,   $\frac{\int_0^{3} x^2dx}{3}$=3, $x_0$= ?

Comment: sorry my bad it's 0 to 3 but the answer still answer doesn't exist.